# I need to get the the user count of a shard by its ID

Tags: javascript, sharding, discord.js

I am using Discord v11.4.2

How do I get the user count of a shard by using the shard's ID? Currently I have this code:

```
client.shard.broadcastEval('this.users.size').then(i => console.log(i))
```

And it logs both user sizes but I need the user size of shard ID 1.
How can I do this?

Comment: Edited your question explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the shard ID with `.broadcastEval('this.shard.id')`, so try using

```
client.shard.broadcastEval('this.shard.id == 1 ? this.users.size : false')
  .then(arr => {
    for (let result of arr)
      if (result) console.log(result);
  });
```

Disclaimer: I'm not very practical with shards, so this could not be the best solution.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)